# i am getting this error when i use flickr api

Tags: flickr

```
import flickrapi
api_key = '<api key>'
api_password = '<api secret>'
flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)
favourites = flickrClient.favorites_getPublicList(user_id='132339441@N02')
photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='132339441@N02', per_page='10')
sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='132339441@N02')
for photo in favourites.photos[0].photo:
    print photo['title']
```

the error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\web\joke.py", line 5, in 
    favourites = flickrClient.favorites_getPublicList(user_id='132339441@N02')
NameError: name 'flickrClient' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `flickrclient` with `c` and `flickrClient` with capital `C`.

So change `flickrclient` to `flickrClient`:

`flickrClient = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)`